# R: Nested for loops and ifelse statements (returning fields based on similar or dissimilar attributes of two dataframes)

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe, nested

Say I have two dataframes:

```
X <- data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),var2 = c("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1"))
Y <- data.frame(var1 = c("B","C","D"),var2 = c("b2","c2","d2"))
```

And I want to create a vector that contains the values in X$var2, except for when the values in Y$var1 match X$var1, for which the values in Y$var2 will be added to the vector instead.

I thought that the following nested for loop that cycles through both dataframes and looks for matches based on a if else function would work, but it doesn't.

```
Z <- c(rep(NA,nrow(X)))

for(i in 1:nrow(X))
{
  for(j in 1:nrow(Y))
  {
    if(X[i,1] == Y[j,1])
    {
      Z[i] <- Y[j,2]
    }else{Z[i] <- X[j,1]}
  }
}
```

Essentially I want Z to be:

```
Z
[1] "a1" "b2" "c2" "d2" "e1" "f1" "g1"
```

I'd appreciate any help!  This simple example is based on a problem I have with a large dataset (for which the level sets of the variables are the same...i.e., I'm not sure how to specify similar levels for my hypothetical dataframes in the simple example above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `merge` function may be helpful:

```
    XY<-merge(X,Y,by="var1",all.x=TRUE)
    ifelse(is.na(XY[,3]),as.character(XY[,2]),as.character(XY[,3]))
    #[1] "a1" "b2" "c2" "d2" "e1" "f1" "g1"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Nicola! Much more simple than attempting a for loop. The "merge" function seems pretty powerful for database management.